# How to use ionic v1 plugin in ionic v3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am new to ionic and typescript. I want to use [this v1 plugin](https://market.ionic.io/plugins/material-action-button#comments) in my project which is in ionic v3. Is there any alternative to this plugin in ionic v3? 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same behavior was added to the Framework, the component is called `FabButton`. Please take a look at [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/fab/FabButton/).

What you want to achieve can be done with the following code:

```
<ion-content>
  <!-- Real floating action button, fixed. It will not scroll with the content -->
  <ion-fab bottom right>
    <button ion-fab mini><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
    <ion-fab-list>
      <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-vimeo"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-googleplus"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-fab-list>
  </ion-fab>

</ion-content>
```

---

**UPDATE**

> I want to make the backdrop blur when the fab is clicked and click on
>   the backdrop will close the fab list

Please take a look at **[this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/myGUpF?p=preview)**. Just like you can see there, we can use a div as the overlay, and then show it and hide it by using the `showOverlay` property.

This is the result:

[image: FabButton demo]

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  appName = 'Ionic Demo';
  showOverlay = false;

  constructor(public navController: NavController) { }

  closeFabButton(fab: any) {
    fab.close();
    this.toggleOverlay();
  }

  toggleOverlay() {
    this.showOverlay = !this.showOverlay;
  }

  optionSelected(fab: any) {
    fab.close();
    this.showOverlay = false;
  }

}
```

**View**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ appName }}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

  <div (click)="closeFabButton(fab)" *ngIf="showOverlay" style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;background-color:black; opacity:0.3;height:100%;width:100%;z-index:9;"></div>

 <ion-fab #fab  bottom right >
   <button (click)="toggleOverlay()" ion-fab>Share</button>
   <ion-fab-list side="top">
     <button (click)="optionSelected(fab)" ion-fab>F</button>
     <button (click)="optionSelected(fab)" ion-fab>T</button>
     <button (click)="optionSelected(fab)" ion-fab>Y</button>
   </ion-fab-list>
 </ion-fab>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: I already used it. I want to make the backdrop blur when the fab is clicked and click on the backdrop will close the fab list

Comment: I've updated the answer, please take a look at it :)